# How do I get a parameter from an API response URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Currently i am running a fetch call like this

```js
const url = "https://urlhere.com/initAPP/oauth2/authorize";

    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "client_id": process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
        "response_type": "code",
        "provision_key": process.env.REACT_APP_PROVISION_KEY,
        "authenticated_userid": process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHENTICATED_USERID 
      })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);

        const redirect_uri = data.redirect_uri.toString();
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(redirect_uri);
        const code = urlParams.get('code')
       
        
        
      } 
    )
```

so it all works fine until we try the url params. when i console log Data it returns like this:

```
redirect_uri : "https://sitehere.sitehere.com?code=U78StlK6sN3hD9CO4ZogvpXvxezFSGU0"
```

when i console log the `redirect_uri` variable it prints out only the URL so that works fine

but when i try to deconstruct that URL that is returned with the `url params` part and try to get the CODE parameter in that url it just returns null. How can i get that specific parameter? am i not using the right variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in the full URL to `URLSearchParams`, it should take only the query string eg. `?code=U78StlK6sN3hD9CO4ZogvpXvxezFSGU0`. You can split this out using `URL`.

```js
 const redirect_uri = "https://sitehere.sitehere.com?code=U78StlK6sN3hD9CO4ZogvpXvxezFSGU0";
 
let params = (new URL(redirect_uri)).searchParams;

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(params);
const code = urlParams.get('code')

console.log(code);
```

Comment: Thats what it was! Thank you Gunwin

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a URL object and use the search to get that value. Something like this

```
const url = new URL(data.redirect_url.toString());
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
const code = params.get('code');
```

Comment: `redirect_url` is already a string so there's no need for `toString()`.

Comment: Not necessarily. Not enough information. Could be an Array of length 1. topched kept the existing code in place, as it was written in the question.